# Simulate s3 bucket using serverless-offline in local

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

I'm using plugin serverless-offline to emulate my lambdas (and API gateway) locally in order to call my lambdas via API REST.
The problem is that some lambdas call my s3 bucket and generate a pre-signed url:

```
url = boto3.client('s3', 'eu-west-3', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4', )).generate_presigned_url(
                ClientMethod='get_object',
                Params={'Bucket': 'my-bucket-test', 'Key': f'{os.getenv("STAGE")}/{self.file_name}'},
                ExpiresIn=3600)
```

I'm using boto3. The problem is that it calls my s3 bucket on AWS instead a local s3 bucket.

I create a s3bucket in local :

```
awslocal s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket-test
```

I add some files to my bucket.

But how can I call this local bucket instead aws bucket ?

Only way I see is to call url but it doesn't generate a presigned-url:

```
https://0.0.0.0:4566/my-bucket-test/image.jpeg
```

I can't do it using boto3 like my code do.

There is a solution?

My other question is : What is the difference between **serverless-offine** and **localstack**? both seems to simulate Api Gateway and lambda, but what about s3?

Comment: localstack supports s3.  Haven't used serverless-offline.

Comment: is localstack an alternative of serverless-offline? Or is it 2 things with different utilities?

Comment: Localstack is not an alternative. Its is cloud service emulator extending its support to many cloud services running over container whereas serverless offline only emulates api gateway and lambda

Comment: Then I can use serverless offline to emulate API gateway and lambda, and also use localstack to emulate s3 for example? right ? So use both at the same time?